# DocuSign: How to get an authorization code programatically

Tags: docusignapi

I have a vuejs SPA. Users have their own accounts with a dashboard. On the dashboard, is a section for PDF signing. All users should have the same PDF displayed, but with their name pre-filled on the PDF, and then 4 spots to sign.

Right now I am stuck on the first part for using the API....which is the auth code.

Why does it seem that the tutorial I followed, requires the owner of the DocuSign account to login and grant rights? I had to do something similar to https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=5665656-3506-46fa-b46d-f6acf3b59268&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com and I got a code in return....but how am I even suppose to implement this for my web app?

1. How do I get the auth code in the background....meaning...I cant have all users go to this URL...am I supposed to do it via ajax GET? I was able to use a correctly formatted URL, but I got the response by visiting the URL in my browser...how can I do this programmatically?
2. I dont get the granting rights part....because there is no way this would be practical where all the users would have to know my private DocuSign account info?
3. Of the (3) oauth methods, which is best for my scenario? Authorization Code Grant, Implicit Grant, or JWT Grant

Answer (score 0):

1. Auth Code Grant was meant for interactive scenarios. It requires UI and a web interface. It cannot be used without UI. Once you have the initial access token, there's a refresh token to be able to obtain a new one without UI, but the initial call requires UI.
2. The users don't have to know your account info, your account info may not be relevant. The user grant a right to your app/integration to make API calls. That is not your account, it is different. It's a clientId/integration key that you use your account to create, but it can be used with any DocuSign user/account.
3. JWT would allow for what you asked in #1 but only after a one-time consent was provided (What you asked in #2) by the end-user. You have to do that for users to enable DocuSign to make API calls on their behalf.

Final word, signers do not need an account in DocuSign. I don't know what you're building, but if your end-user just signs - they don't need an account and a lot of 1-3 is moot.